# Transit through Heathrow airport

Tags: transit, lhr

Do I need to go through the UK Border Control if I have a connecting flight between Terminal 2 and T5 in Heathrow airport London?

Answer (score 2):

Not unless you are connecting to a UK domestic flight or a flight to Dublin.

Or you need to collect and recheck your bag for some reason

Comment: Or if they weren't able to through-check their bags (eg connection was actually on 2 different tickets from airlines that don't play nicely with each other WRT interlining)

Comment: @Gagravarr Agreed